# How to join (sum) columns in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file with the structure shown below. I'd like to join them into one column (sum them arithmetically and save as a one column).

file structure:

```
1   4   1   4
2   5   2   5
3   6   3   6
```

this what I'd like to get:

```
10
14
18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
awk '{ x=0; for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) x += $i; print x }' file
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a one more question; How to separate this values using commas?

Answer (score 6):

For most purposes, I think it's best to use an external program such as AWK or Perl (see cnicutar's answer for an AWK approach); but if you prefer, you can do this in pure Bash, as follows:

```
while read -a arr ; do
    i=0
    for field in ${arr[*]} ; do
        (( i += field ))
    done
    echo $i
done < input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

Or more tersely — but also more hackishly — you could write:

```
while read ; do
    echo $(( ${REPLY//$'\t'/+} ))
done < input-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

(the latter is roughly equivalent to the (also hackish) sed-based approaches of various other answers).

Comment: I don't think `arr` adds anything nonpiratey to the first solution. You could just as well use `while read -r; do i=0; for field in $REPLY; do ...`, effectively deferring the word splitting from `read` to `for`. An alternative for the second solution (for which +1): `echo $(($(printf %s+ $REPLY)0))`; that works with arbitrary whitespace, including trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

@cnicutar gave a standard awk solution, I just add a sed one-liner (with bc) for fun:

```
kent$  cat f
1 4 1 4
2 5 2 5
3 6 3 6

kent$  sed 's/ \+/+/g' f|bc
10
14
18
```

the `\+` in sed line is just in case your columns are separated by multi-spaces.

as @ruakh suggested,  `sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/+/g' f|bc` is more generic and reliable.

Comment: This version of the `sed` solution is the best so far. It involves only one invocation, doesn't break on consecutive spaces and doesn't use nonstandard syntax. The only improvement I can think of would be to trim leading and trailing space first.

Comment: @ruakh you are right, when I posted the answer, the question showed as space... :(, the distance between 'columns' was just one char width. well, `[[:space:]]` is anyway reliable. I will change the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use sed to replace whitespaces with pluses, then `bc` to get the results:

```
sed 's/\s\+/+/g' input | bc
```

Comment: Note that `\s` is non-standard and will not necessarily be available on non-GNU `sed`. Using `[[:space:]]` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (the awk solution is better, but it's nice too know that there are alternatives :))

```
sed 's/ /+/g' test.txt | sed -E 's/^(.*)$/echo $((\1))/' | bash
```

Comment: Generating `sh` code and piping to `bash` is more dangerous than necessary.

Comment: @Sorpigal: that's one of the reasons why I don't recommend using it. It's just here for completeness

Answer (score 1):

And here's the same thing in Perl (though I am sure it can be done more tersely):

```
perl -nle '$s=0; $s+=$_ for split; print $s'
```

Oh, and to do what your title asks (sum over *columns* instead of rows):

```
perl -nle '$i=0; $s[$i++]+=$_ for split; END { print "@s" }'
```

Because … Perl.